# Haskell CoreSyn library -- how does one refer to built-in IO types?

Tags: haskell, code-generation, ghc, codegen

I am trying to see how the following Haskell code gets translated to the data types defined in the Coresyn library.

```
module Main where 

f :: Double -> IO () 
f = putStrLn . show

main :: IO ()
main = f 3
```

I can obtain the core code made human readable by -ddump-simpl, but what I don't understand is how one would translate this into the data structure for Core in the Coresyn library.  In particular, I don't know how to translate the "IO ()" bit.  My guess is that it involves first building something like TyCon "IO" unitTy but what is one supposed to put for IO. I also don't know how to call a built-in function like putStrLn using the constructors in Coresyn.

How does one build the built-in IO primitives "IO a" and "putStrLn" using the Coresyn library?

Comment: The `IO` type, and its corresponding constructor, is [actually defined within Haskell itself](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/54d6b20192fe6fc244248c7766533a768c591bae/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC/Types.hs#L219-L233), although it does involve a bit of magic.

Comment: Thank you.  In the TysPrim package realWorldStatePrimTy is defined.  In the PrelNames package they also define a name for ioTyConName.  So I guess I could define an IO TyCon by saying that IO is a newtype TyCon with name ioTyConName.  I guess I'm just a little confused as to if there is an export of IO as a TyCon directly, especially since realWorldStatePrimTy is exported along with realWorldTyCon, or if I should build IO as a new type applied State# RealWorld.